# Why when I log in my two screens shows the same image automatically?

Tags: multiple-monitors, login

When I log in on my computer, first my two monitors shows their own part of a larger desktop, then automatically changes to the same image on both screens, but I don't want to happen this, Is there any configuration to avoid this?

About my hardware:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset 
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Comment: This question has not information added in it for a very long time and probably describes a bug in old package versions. I have flagged it to a moderator so it can be closed. If you think that this is still a valid question and that you are still suffering for this issue you can always flag it so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

Similar Ubuntu bugs have been reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ and fixed within the last year, I believe. This only happened to me after I began using openSUSE.

Answer (score 0):

System, Preferences, Monitors. Untick "Same image in all monitors", arrange to suit. Apply. This setup should now happen automatically next time you log in.

Comment: that's what i do, but them still happens the same every time turn on my computer =/